# how to use kobert model on flutter?

Tags: flutter, machine-learning, model

I customized kobert model using this code.

```
model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('skt/kobert-base-v1', num_labels=6)
```

and I fine-tuned this "model" with my custom train data. Then, I save model with this code.

```
model.save_pretrained('.')
```

I have this files: 'config.json' and 'model.safetensors'.

I wanna load my custom kobertmodel on Flutter.

How can I do with this files?